# Force User Log In with a Windows Service

Tags: windows, service, authentication

Is it possible for a Windows service to force a user to login from the windows user login screen?  I've seen where LogMeIn can do it.  This is assuming, of course, that I have both the username and password for the user.

Is LogMeIn using an actual method (non-automated), or are they simply quickly automating the task of logging in my selecting the username and password fields and typing it in?

Comment: LogMeIn, or any application, cannot type anything on the interactive window station when it's locked; check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a WindowStation, and a Desktop inside that. Your service would create the WindowStation and connect that to the user you want to log in, then I suppose you would periodically take a screenshot of the created desktop to present somewhere else.

You may want to start reading the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and linked pages, then ask a more specific question.

I don't know if this method can be used to log in at the Console (the window station attached to the physical video card/keyboard of the computer), but if this has to happen automatically I'd avoid using the Console, but a separate Window Station.

EDIT: as it happens to say on the very page I linked (my bad), if a session for the user exists and the service tries to connect to it, it is opened; if it does not exist then it is created anew, and a desktop (named "default") is attached to it. If your service only has to log the interactive user in you should use the auto-login feature of windows instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can auto login using Windows.

You didn't specify OS but for [Windows 7/8 read this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872306.aspx), and for Server 2003/2008 (and possibly 2012, but I haven't checked)
check out [this Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324737).

Comment: That has to be done before the log in, though.  This is something that, while at the log in screen, I would like to activate.  Similar to how LogMeIn does it when you've remoted into another computer and it offers to log in for you.

Comment: LogMeIn is not using the traditional login screen that you see. So, no it's not automatically typing in your username and password.It's using it's own RDP app (remote desktop protocol). Look up Microsoft's RDP and Terminal Services.